# Specifying dtype=object for numpy.gradient

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization, scientific-computing

Is there a way to specify the dtype for [numpy.gradient](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)?

I'm using an array of subarrays and it's throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty([3, 3], dtype=object)
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok'])
while not it.finished:
    i = it.multi_index[0]
    j = it.multi_index[1]
    a[it.multi_index] = np.array([i, j])
    it.iternext()
print(a)
```

which outputs

```
[[array([0, 0]) array([0, 1]) array([0, 2])]
 [array([1, 0]) array([1, 1]) array([1, 2])]
 [array([2, 0]) array([2, 1]) array([2, 2])]]
```

I would like `print(np.gradient(a))` to return

```
array(
    [[array([[1, 0],[0, 1]]), array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]), array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])],
     [array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]), array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]), array([[1, 0],[0, 1]])],
     [array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]), array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]), array([[1, 0],[0, 1]])]],
    dtype=object)
```

Notice that, in this case, the gradient of the vector field is an identity tensor field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you working an array of `dtype` object?  That's more work than using a 2d array.

e.g.

```
In [53]: a1=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

In [54]: a1
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [55]: np.gradient(a1)
Out[55]: 
[array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]]),
 array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])]
```

or working column by column, or row by row

```
In [61]: [np.gradient(i) for i in a1.T]
Out[61]: [array([ 2.,  2.,  2.]), array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])]

In [62]: [np.gradient(i) for i in a1]
Out[62]: [array([ 1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.]), array([ 1.,  1.])]
```

`dtype=object` only make sense if the subarrays/lists differ in type and/or shape.  And even then it doesn't add much to a regular Python list.

==============================

I can take your 2d `a`, and make a 3d array with:

```
In [126]: a1=np.zeros((3,3,2),int)

In [127]: a1.flat[:]=[i for  i in a.flatten()]

In [128]: a1
Out[128]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

Or I could produce the same thing with `meshgrid`:

```
In [129]: X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(3),np.arange(3),indexing='ij')
In [130]: a2=np.array([Y,X]).T
```

When I apply `np.gradient` to that I get 3 arrays, each (3,3,2) in shape.

```
In [136]: ga1=np.gradient(a1)

In [137]: len(ga1)
Out[137]: 3

In [138]: ga1[0].shape
Out[138]: (3, 3, 2)
```

It looks like the 1st 2 arrays have the values you want, so it's just a matter of rearranging them.

```
In [141]: np.array(ga1[:2]).shape
Out[141]: (2, 3, 3, 2)

In [143]: gga1=np.array(ga1[:2]).transpose([1,2,0,3])

In [144]: gga1.shape
Out[144]: (3, 3, 2, 2)

In [145]: gga1[0,0]
Out[145]: 
array([[ 1., -0.],
       [-0.,  1.]])
```

If they must go back into a (3,3) object array, I could do:

```
In [146]: goa1=np.empty([3,3],dtype=object)

In [147]: for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        goa1[i,j]=gga1[i,j]
   .....:         

In [148]: goa1
Out[148]: 
array([[array([[ 1., -0.],
       [-0.,  1.]]),
        array([[ 1., -0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]),
        array([[ 1., -0.],
       ...
       [ 0.,  1.]]),
        array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])]], dtype=object)
```

I still wonder what's the point to working with a object array.

Comment: I'm not worried about 'sense' in some sort of mathematical sense.  My focus is on using the numpy function.